# VB.NET: Translate an ARGB Color Into a Hex Color

Tags: vb.net

I need to convert an argb stored in a `System.Drawing.Color` into a hex color, but I can't find out how. I found how to translate hex into argb, but not vice versa. I would prefer that this would be done with colortranslator, but any method will do.

Thanks in advance.

-A very confused person that probably doesn't know what they're doing

Comment: What "Color" class/structure are you using?

Comment: I'm trying to use Drawing.Color

Comment: for a system.drawing color this can be used: `System.Drawing.Colortranslator.ToHTML(theColor)`

Comment: @Plutonix That works great for HTML, but will do `"Red"` for a red color, not `#FFFF0000`.

Comment: @itrollin98 In that case, my answer shoudl work fine for you

Comment: ahh! I thought it was more comprehensive

Comment: It worked, thanks for the speed. On most sites it takes 3-4 days.

Comment: If you always need the hex number, you just use: color.ToArgb().ToString("X8")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends slightly on which type of `Color` class or structure you're using.  With `System.Drawing.Color`, you can use:

```
Private Function ToHex(color As System.Drawing.Color) As String
    Return "#" & color.A.ToString("X2") & color.R.ToString("X2") & color.G.ToString("X2") & color.B.ToString("X2")
End Function
```

Comment: I tried using this. How would I translate the recieved hex color into a string? I used `ToHex(TextBox2.Text)` and it said String cannot be converted into System.Drawing.Color.

Comment: @itrollin98 This is a string.  If you want to convert it to a Color, you can use `ColorTranslator.FromHtml(theString)`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.colortranslator.fromhtml(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use following for the same:
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Hex(System.Drawing.Color.AntiqueWhite().ToArgb())
Mark it solved if it works.